# Read file line by line, and edit line if it matches regex

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that goes through hundreds of TXT files in a folder. These txt files can be from 2KB to 80GB, but some lines need to be deleted/edited out depending on if there's a regex match in the line.

Every solution I've seen involves using `file.readlines()`, which would load each file into RAM but that wouldn't be ideal for the larger files. Right now I have a script that goes through each line in the files, I can't find anything to edit or delete the lines though.

Is this even possible in python?

Comment: Iterate over the file itself, and lines will only be loaded into memory as needed.

Comment: You can read lines one at a time using `file.readline()` in order to avoid loading the entire file into memory. To remove lines, I would suggest writing lines you want to keep to a new file as you iterate over the original, then just remove the original and rename the new file once you've completed. This is going to be the easiest to code as long as the extra disk usage is acceptable

Comment: Of course - you can read line by line or even in larger specified chunks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I avoid `readlines()` in Python because it's almost never needed. This is a case where just iterating over the lines is much more concise, and saves memory the way you want as well.

Most importantly, you need to **create a temporary file** to store the results, and then rename it into place when you're done.

```
import os, re, tempfile

FILES = ['source.txt', 'file.txt']

SHOULD_DELETE = re.compile('delete me').search

def edit_line(line):
    return line.replace('hello world', 'goodby world')

for source_path in FILES:
    dir = os.path.dirname(source_path)
    # open the source file normally
    with open(source_path) as source:
        try:
            # make a hidden tempfile to stage your changes in
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', suffix='.', dir=dir) as target:
                # iterate over lines in the source file (each line ends with \n)
                for line in source:
                    # skip lines that need deleting
                    if not SHOULD_DELETE(line):
                        # do any edits here, and then call target.write
                        target.write(edit_line(line))
                # now swap the edited copy into place
                os.rename(target.name, source_path)
        # tempfile tries to delete the temporary file, but it's gone now
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

Note: You can use `NamedTemporaryFile(..., delete=False)` to avoid the `try`/`except FileNotFound` block, but doing so risks leaving the temporary file as trash on disk if your program exits early, e.g. from Ctrl+D or being killed.